# Does upgrading Android application delete files from private data directory?

Tags: android

Does upgrading Android application delete files from private data directory?

I have tested this by doing the following on a real device

1. From eclipse running V1 of the app and creating a file called GodLovesKittens.txt
2. From eclipse running V2 of the app and checking if GodLovesKittens.txt exists

I want to be 100% sure that files in the data directory do not get deleted on upgrade on all version of Android

Thanks
B

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Possible to preserve data when upgrading app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673410/android-possible-to-preserve-data-when-upgrading-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are the only instances I can think of where your app data is deleted:

1. The user chooses to clear your applications user data
2. You delete the data yourself via your application
3. Your application is uninstalled
4. A rooted user navigates to your data and deletes it manually
5. The entire phone is wiped