# Update ionic 2 app without loss of user data?

Tags: android, ionic2, cordova-plugins, couchbase-lite

I am developing an app using ionic2 and Couchbase Lite (for offline data storage). After releasing the app, how can I update app without losing the user data?

Answer (score 0):

That is not really an issue.
In android user data is only deleted when the user uninstalls the app and not when an update is installed from the play store.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359256/does-upgrading-android-application-delete-files-from-private-data-directory)