# does android delete an application package when installing a new version of it?

Tags: android

My application has already saved lots of information on the user's device and now I feel I need to release a new version of my app. But, how can I prevent all those data from being deleted if my old app's package directory is going to be removed by android?

Answer (score 2):

Data saved in a database or the SharedPreferences won't be deleted if you increase the version number an keep the package name. If you change the rows of an database you have to increase the version number of it also.

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani Unfortunately, not but there are some similar question here on StackOverflow.   For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673410/android-possible-to-preserve-data-when-upgrading-app) and [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359256/does-upgrading-android-application-delete-files-from-private-data-directory)