# Android get data of previous version of the application

Tags: android

Maybe my question has been asked before, but I couldn't find the proper keyword for searching this.

So I was assigned to develop an update of an application which will be uploaded soon. But I have one big problem. The users who have already installed the previous version may have some data which may be lost when updated. The data is stored in this location

> /data/data/app_package_name/shared_prefs/data.xml

I need to browse the text inside the data.xml in order to get required fragments for using them in the new version. How can I check if the application was installed previously and only then read the user data only once when installing the update?

Comment: App private data is not deleted when upgrading app. App private data is only removed when app is uninstalled. See [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673410/android-possible-to-preserve-data-when-upgrading-app) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359256/does-upgrading-android-application-delete-files-from-private-data-directory)

Comment: Thanks for information. But how is it possible to read that data only once when installing the update. I don't need to check the existence of that data every time launching the activity.

Comment: See [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) - Call openFileInput() to read from internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Comment: Well , but is there a method overriding which I can perform that action only once when installing the update or when the user first launches the app after updating?

Comment: Have you used sharedpreferences? You need to use sharedpreferences to save a parameter (say version number) when user first install app then check for that parameter upon running app. If existing parameter is less, then read data...- same like when show what's new dialog - let me know if you need sample

Comment: I just added answer on how to read data when user first update app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main activity:

```
    private static final String PRIVATE_PREF = "MainActivity";
    private static final String VERSION_KEY = "1";
```

In onCreate():

```
    init();
```

init() method:

```
private void init() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref    = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int currentVersionNumber        = 0;

        int savedVersionNumber          = sharedPref.getInt(VERSION_KEY, 0);

        try {
                PackageInfo pi          = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            currentVersionNumber    = pi.versionCode;
            } catch (Exception e) {}


            if (currentVersionNumber > savedVersionNumber) {            
                readData();

                Editor editor   = sharedPref.edit();

                editor.putInt(VERSION_KEY, currentVersionNumber);
                editor.commit();
            }
    }
```

readData() method - something like:

```
    private void readData() {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            is.close();
        } catch(OutOfMemoryError om){
            om.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = sb.toString();
}
```

Make sure you change the VERSION_KEY when you release new app version.

For parsing XML, refer to [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)